# Extract Created date and last login from firebase authentication using Python

Tags: python, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Currently my python code gets the user id and email of all users from firebase authentication using the firebase admin SDK, however I am unable find the correct syntax to extract the user metadata such as the created and last login date/time (which according to the documentation is in milliseconds). There are a few documentation that shows ways to do this, but it is not working for me.

My code:

```
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import auth

cred=credentials.Certificate('firebasesdk.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    "databaseURL": "myurl",
})

page = auth.list_users()
    while page:
        for user in page.users:
            print('User email: ' + user.email)
            print('User id: ' + user.uid)
```

I tried using `user.metadata.creationTime`and `user.madata.getLastSignInTimestamp` and  but it does not work with python. I was looking through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174178/get-created-date-and-last-login-date-from-firuser-with-firebase-3) post regarding this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the [`ExportedUsers` result](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#exporteduserrecord) for `list_users` does not include the metadata for the users. In that case you'll need to call `get_user(...)` for each UID in the result to get the full [`UserRecord`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#exporteduserrecord), and then find the timestamps in the metadata.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is `user.metadata.creation_timestamp` and `user.metadata.last_sign_in_timestamp`. See API reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#firebase_admin.auth.UserMetadata

Answer (score 0):

To get `creationTime` and `getLastSignInTimeStamp`, you can access `creation_timestamp` and `last_sign_in_timestamp` from the `user_metadata` field. For example

```
from firebase_admin import auth

page = auth.list_users()
    while page:
        for user in page.users:
            print('User creation time: ' + user.user_metadata.creation_timestamp)
            print('User last sign in time: ' + user.user_metadata.last_sign_in_timestamp)
        page = page.get_next_page()
```

or

```
from firebase_admin import auth

for user in auth.list_users().iterate_all():
    print('User creation time: ' + user.user_metadata.creation_timestamp)
    print('User last sign in time: ' + user.user_metadata.last_sign_in_timestamp)
```

Each timestamp is an integer representing milliseconds since the epoch.

More info:

`user` is a [ExportedUserRecord](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#firebase_admin.auth.ExportedUserRecord) which inherits from [UserRecord](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#firebase_admin.auth.UserRecord)

`user_metadata` is [UserMetadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#firebase_admin.auth.UserMetadata)